# Event handler when data is in list

Tags: c#

I'm learning C#, and now have a class defined like this

```
class A : EventArg
{
    public int i=0;
}
```

And in another `cs` file I define an event handler like this

```
public event EventHandler<A> AData;
 protected virtual void Selected(A a)
        {
            EventHandler<A> handler = AData;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                var arg = new A(){i=a.i}

                handler(this, arg);
            }
        }
```

Now I want to send a `List<A>` of data instead of a single class instance like above.

Comment: Do you want the event to give the handler a collection of integers instead of one single integer? If that's the case, redefine `public int i = 0;` as `public List<int> Integers = new List<int>();`. Also, you don't have to create a new instance of A inside `Selected(A a)`. You can just pass the handler the `a` that the caller gave to `Selected()`.

Comment: So use `EventHandler<List<A>>`. What part of that are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would encapsulate the list in the event arg class. It doesn't make sense to have a list of EventArgs.

```
class ListEventArg : EventArg
{
    public List<A> ListOfA { get; set; }
}
```